# How to find selected path on svg image in xamarin forms

Tags: javascript, c#, svg, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using a C# library in which I'm unable to select path of a svg image.

I'm developing a hybrid mobile application, using the Xamarin.Forms platform where I have to display svg image and I have to highlight the selected parts. So, I have added SVG nuget package. The SVG image is working fine but, I am unable to find the selected parts. Can anyone please help me?

```
var svgPaths = new List<string>
{
    "SampleApp.Images.sample1.svg",
};

var grid = new Grid
{
    RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection(),
    ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
};

var svgPath = svgPaths[0];
var svgImage = new SvgImage
{
    SvgPath = svgPath,
    SvgAssembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
    HeightRequest = 400,
    WidthRequest = 400,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    BackgroundColor = Color.White
};

grid.Children.Add(svgImage);
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: What do you mean by selected parts?